# IE modifying stylesheet rule does not refresh

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, stylesheet

I'm adding a rule to a stylesheet via JS and then trying to edit that rule. It works fine elsewhere but not in IE.

I know about the difference of accessing the stylesheet & rules in IE, I guess there must be a difference in modifying existing properties too, see my (IE only) example:

```
<style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" id="tmp-style"></style>
<h3>Test</h3>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
    sheet.addRule('h3', 'background-color: red', 0);
    console.log( sheet.rules[0].selectorText + ' = ' + sheet.rules[0].style['background-color'] );
    sheet.rules[0].style['background-color'] = 'blue';
    console.log( sheet.rules[0].selectorText + ' = ' + sheet.rules[0].style['background-color'] );
</script>
```

The H3 remains red and the console show:

```
LOG: h3 = undefined 
LOG: h3 = blue
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it turns out that to access the style properties this way via JS in IE you must use the camel case notation to access them, e.g.:

```
sheet.rules[0].style['backgroundColor'] = 'blue';
```